# How to calculate the mean of the square of the distance between two randomly chosen points from the unit square

Tags: probability-theory

I have the following homework question:

> Two points are chosen randomly from a unit square. Let $D$ denote the
>   distance between the points. Calculate $ED^{2}$.

**What I tried:**

Denote $X$ as the first point that was chosen and $Y$ as the second
point. Then $D=|Y-X|$.

$F_{D}(r)=P(|Y-X|\leq r)$ equals to the probability that $Y$ is
in a closed ball with radius $r$ around $X$.

This is where I have a hard time - even calculating the area of this closed ball (the part of it that is contained in the unit square) is difficult for me. Also, even if I do calculate it - what do I do next ? I want to "sum" for all options of $X$ but since we are dealing with a continues case here it seems that I should integrate the function I am getting for the area - over all points $x$ in the unit square.

I need help with this exercie: Am I on the right track ? If so can someone please help suggest a way to calculate that area ? (did I undersatand correctly what to do after I find this area ?)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why the downvote ? maybe I can improve the question ?

Comment: I too can't understand why down vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In absence of other information, I am assuming the the points are distributed uniformly on the unit square. Let $I=[0,1]$. The sample space is $\Omega =I^2 \times I^2$, and the measure is the Lebesgue measure.

Then $D^2((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = (x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$, and we have (grinding through the four integrals, or two if you take symmetry into account)
$E D^2 = \int_\Omega D^2 dm = \int_I \int_I \int_I \int_I ((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2)dx_1 d y_1 dx_2 dy_2 = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Well, in this case, if I understand what you are asking, both the cumulative distribution and joint density would be a functions $f,F:I^2\times I^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. But $f$ is particularly simple with the uniform distribution, it would be just $1$.

Comment: I removed my comment, I think that I just treated $D^2$ the wrong way and that confused me. $D^2$ is a random vector (of $4$ dimensions) and the density of two points in the unit square is given be distance (like you wrote). Is this explanation correct ? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Well, the density of the uniform distribution is just $1$. Then you are just averaging $D^2$ over $I^2 \times I^2$ (or $I^4$, of course). Think (very loosely) of the density as being the measure of the 'infinitesimal volume' $d x_1 d y_1 d x_2 d y_2$. Since the distribution is uniform, the density will be just $\frac{1}{\text{volume}}$ (which is $1$ here).